Is "complete induction" sometimes synonymous with "proof by exhaustion?"
I was reading the Wikipedia page on proof by exhaustion and the introductory paragraph (as of time of writing) says the following:

Proof by exhaustion, also known as proof by cases, proof by case analysis, complete induction or the brute force method, [...]

(Emphasis mine.) I found the term "complete induction" here surprising, since I have always heard that term used to refer to a specific form of the principle of mathematical induction.
The Wikipedia page does not cite an instance where "complete induction" is used in the sense of a proof by cases. Is the article correct and this term is indeed used to mean "proof by cases," or should the article be updated?

I have never heard of the term "complete induction" used for anything until now, and a search seems to reveal that it is generally synonymous with "strong induction": an induction proof where the induction step proves $P(k)$ by assuming $P(j)$ for all $j<k$. It seems most likely that the article is incorrect.

It is "sometimes synonymous in some sense, I think.  Induction takes one case, proves it is true in that case and then proves if it is true in one case it is true in the subsequent case.  Whereas proof by exhaustion usually means proving it true in all possible cases.  They are, in effect, largely the same, but the technique is usually different.  So I completely agree with Misha Lavrov.
